# What's the best way to perform math on a floored date in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

This is related to [Floor a date in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85373/floor-a-date-in-sql-server), but I'm taking it one step further:

I'm writing a query on a SQL Server table and I want to get all records for the current calendar year and the previous calendar year. So, right now, I'd want a query to return all records between January 1st, 2008 and today. But come January 1st, 2010, I want it to return records no older than 2009.

Essentially, I want to floor the current date to the beginning of the year and then subtract 1.

After rummaging through some SQL Server documentation, I came up with this:

```
   WHERE create_date >= CAST((CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS int) -1) AS varchar)
```

but it feels kind of ugly. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use the year function on create_date as well?

```
WHERE YEAR(create_date) >= (YEAR(GETDATE()) -1)
```

This assumes (as you did) that there are no records in the database greater than today's date

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest assigning a variable with the date lastyear-01-01, either by making an UDF for it, or something like

```
DECLARE @startOfLastYear DATETIME
SET @startOfLastYear = CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1 AS VARCHAR) + '-01-01'
```

Then do the query:

```
WHERE  create_date >= @startOfLastYear
```

Because of two reasons:

1. Using YEAR() or any other function
   on data from tables (i.e.
   YEAR(create_date)) makes indices
   unusable and decreases the
   performance of the query
2. The variable name tells exactly what it is, and reading the code is easier.