# SQL returning 0 records / date problem?

Tags: sql

The SQL below is returning 0 records when I know there are records that match - I think it's the date causing me problems.

Here is the SQL:

```
 exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM [dbo].[QuizAnswersCompleted]
 WHERE [dbo].[QuizAnswersCompleted].[QuizProfileID] = @QuizProfileID0
 AND [dbo].[QuizAnswersCompleted].[DateCompleted] = @DateCompleted1
',N'@QuizProfileID0 int,@DateCompleted1 datetime',@QuizProfileID0=31,@DateCompleted1='Aug 19 2009  4:29:03:000PM'
```

And here is a screen shot of the records that match in the DB:

[alt text http://photos-d.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc1/hs145.snc1/5371_117422998930_749683930_2374147_5891781_n.jpg](http://photos-d.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc1/hs145.snc1/5371_117422998930_749683930_2374147_5891781_n.jpg)

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with date/times like you have, there are fractions of a second too, in your query you use 'Aug 19 2009  4:29:03:000PM', the screen capture only shows seconds. if you want an exact match like you are doing you need to know the entire time:

```
select convert(char(23),YourDate,121) FROM YourTable
```

try "flooring" your date: [Floor a date in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85373/floor-a-date-in-sql-server)

Comment: Agreed.  The max resolution of a DateTime is 3 milliseconds.  That leaves roughly 333 possible values between 4:29:03:000 and 4:29:04:000.

Comment: Running a function on a column as part of a where clause can result in poor query performance (on larger tables), as the server will be unable to use statistics or indexes for the column. Whilst it seems a bit of a hack, you could use the predicate: `WHERE [DateCompleted] BETWEEN @date AND @dateUpper` where @date is the original date you are after, and @dateUpper is a date 999ms later.

Comment: problem is the SQL is generated by SubSonic so I can't adjust the query - I'll have to come up with a different solution that doesn't use date which isn't a problem - thanks for all the help!