# T-SQL code to get a DateTime contain only Month and Year from any DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

Given a table `Event` containing a field called `EventTime` of type DateTime and that the value will contain both date and time elements, I need create a summary query which counts the number of events in each month.

The resulting type of the Group By field must also be Date Time with a 0 time element and set to 1st day of the month.

This is what I have so far but its not very elegant and I'm not sure its particularly efficient.

```
  SELECT COUNT(1) AS [CountOfEvents],
         DATEADD(d, 1 - DAY(EventTime), DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, EventTime))) AS [Month]
    FROM [Event]
GROUP BY DATEADD(d, 1 - DAY(EventTime), DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, EventTime)))
```

Better suggestions for either more efficiency or elegance?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this floors to the month:

```
select dateadd(month,datediff(m,0,GETDATE()),0);
```

output:

```
-----------------------
2009-10-01 00:00:00.000

(1 row(s) affected)
```

so try this:

```
SELECT
   COUNT(*) as CountOF
    ,dateadd(month,datediff(m,0,EventTime),0)
    FROM [Event]
    GROUP BY dateadd(month,datediff(m,0,EventTime),0)
    ORDER BY 2
```

Comment: the key is to floor by the unit you are interested in (in this case month), see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85373/floor-a-date-in-sql-server/85379#85379

Comment: What is the purpose of ORDER BY 2 ?

Comment: it will sort the query by the second column.  When I ran this query  on my system, it was difficult to check the results, so I sorted them. When I pasted it in here, I just left that there. remove if you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(1) AS [CountOfEvents],
    DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [EventTime]), 0) AS [Month]
FROM [Event]
GROUP BY DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [EventTime]), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `MONTH(GetDate())` T-SQL Function you can use.

Also are you just trying to strip the time from a date time?

If so, try this:

```
DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, GetDate()), 0)
```

It's a bit cleaner and more readable.

Comment: Thanks I am striping the Time and that is an element in my expression (look closely you can see it) however I don't want to strip the Year I just want to set the day to the 1st.  So the MONTH function isn't all that helpful.

Answer (score 0):

may be this is more 'readable':

```
SELECT
 COUNT(1) AS [CountOfEvents],
 CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, EventTime, 112)) + 1 - DAY(EventTime) AS [Month]
FROM [Event]
GROUP BY CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, EventTime, 112)) + 1 - DAY(EventTime)
```