# Query to select the month and nos of weekend and public holiday in that month

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

My database table Holiday  includes field ad Holidaydate->datetime , WeekendHoliday->bit, PublicHoliday->bit 
I want the nos of weekendholiday and also publicholiday  in a specific month year.

My table values are as(example)

```
Holidaydate       WeekendHoliday       PublicHoliday 
-----------       --------------       -------------
4/02/2012             true                 false
4/20/2012             true                 false
5/3/2012              true                 False
5/30/2012             false                true
4/05/2013             false                true
```

So now output should be like this:

```
year      Month   count(weekend)   count(public)
----      -----   --------------   -------------
2012      April      2               0
2012      May        1               1
2013      April      0               1
```

Comment: You need more detail in this question.  What do 3 and 5 in your desired output represent, counts of something, if so, what?  Please explain a little more.  Based on your question `select 'April' as Month, '3' as Weekend, '5' as Public` would satisfy the question.

Comment: Ya the 3 is counting the numbers of weekend holiday in the month of april and 5 represents the count the public holiday in the month of april also if the value of Weekend(field) is true then count else not, if the value of Public(field) is true then count....

Comment: There is no `boolean` data type in SQL Server, did you mean `bit`? And your comments about 3 and 5 do not at all match the data you showed, e.g. you say that 3 is the number of weekend holidays in April, but your data shows there are only 2. You need to explain your logic more precisely. And which of the two result sets that you showed do you actually want? The first one with 3 columns or the second one with 4 columns? Or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     SELECT year(holidaydate),month(holidaydate), 
            sum(case Weekend when true then 1 else 0 end) wkEnd, 
            sum(case PublicHoliday when true then 1 else 0 end) pubHol
      FROM Holiday 
      GROUP BY year(holidaydate),month(holidaydate)
```

I don't have SQL server available. THis is tested on mysql. Here  year and month are function to return the year and month of date. Syntax of *CASE* should be same across database.

Comment: this will not work in mssal because of the 'case weekend when true' replace with 'case weekend when 'true'' Also the count will count both 1 and 0. Replace with sum or remove the 'else 0'

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest to use a [calendar table](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2010/07/19/calendar-table-and-datetime-functions.aspx) for such kind of queries.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way how you could [aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) your data:

```
WITH partitioned AS (
  SELECT
    MonthDate = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0),
    WeekendHoliday,
    PublicHoliday
  FROM Holiday
)
SELECT
  Year           = YEAR(MonthDate),
  Month          = DATENAME(MONTH, MonthDate),
  Weekends       = COUNT(NULLIF(WeekendHoliday, 'false')),
  PublicHolidays = COUNT(NULLIF(PublicHoliday , 'false'))
FROM partitioned
GROUP BY
  MonthDate
```

The `partitioned` [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) [replaces every date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504664/t-sql-code-to-get-a-datetime-contain-only-month-and-year-from-any-datetime) with the first of the same month, and that value is then used for [grouping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) and [deriving years](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx) and [month names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx) from. Each [`NULLIF()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) transforms every `'false'` (`0`) value into `NULL` so the corresponding [`COUNT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) omits it. As a result, only the `'true'` (`1`) values are counted.