# How to make bar chart using stored procedure values directly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, crystal-reports

[Query to select the month and nos of weekend and public holiday in that month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810642/query-to-select-the-month-and-nos-of-weekend-and-public-holiday-in-that-month)

by using the select query in above link i have made a stored procedure in SQL Server 2005.

Now I get the output (as an example) like this:

```
year      Month   count(weekendholiday)   count(publicholiday)
----      -----   --------------   -------------
2012      April      2               1
2012      May        1               1
2013      April      0               1
```

Can I use these values in Crystal Reports (asp.net C#) directly to make bar chart?

I want specific year in X-axis and counts in Y-axis.

There should be 2 bar which shows 1.nos. of weekend 2. nos. of public holiday

How can I do that?

Something like this:

```
  |
 3|  
  |          Weekend
  |            -----
 2|            |   |
  |            |   |
  |            |   |public
 1|            |   |---    
  |            |   |   |
--|-----|---------|---------|----------|-------
       3/2012   4/2012    5/2012      6/2012
```

Comment: I didnt get both bar I am getting only one bar i.e. weekend or public

Comment: Can you post the relevant code snippet?

Comment: I am not using any code. I am following the steps as in below link http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LMXCqOS1Yzw

Comment: Something what in this link http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hboXnn1w0rg

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straight forward if i understood correctly: http://speedy.sh/PwCWn/sample-report.rpt