# How can I get the date of the first second of the year with SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on a purging procedure on SQL Server 2005 which has to delete all rows in a table  older than 1 year ago + time passed in the current year.

Ex: If I execute the procedure today **6-10-2009** it has to delete rows older than **2008-01-01 00:00** (that is 2007 included and backwards).

How can I get the date of the first second of the year?

I've tried this:

`select cast((DATEPART(year, getdate()) -1 )AS DATETIME);`

but I get `1905-07-02 00:00:00.000` and not `2008-01-01 00:00` (as I *wrongly* expected).

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work:

```
select cast('01 jan' + CAST((DATEPART(year, getdate())-1) as varchar) AS DATETIME);
```

*(I know it's not the "best" solution and probably involves more casts than necessary, but it works, and for how this will be used it seems to be a pragmatic solution!)*

Comment: Hmm.. Interesting how the other answer to this question (at the time of writing) has 8 upvotes, whilst mine has only 1 up and 1 down vote, yet mine is the only solution that gives the correct answer. (ie. For today's date (6 Oct 2009) the result is 2008-01-01 00:00:00, whilst Raj's solution returns 2009-01-01 00:00:00)

Comment: I like SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,CAST(YEAR(GETDATE())-1 AS VARCHAR) + '0101',112) or SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,CAST(YEAR(GETDATE())-1 AS VARCHAR),112) more, because it specifies input format.

Comment: @CraigTP: I upvoted you myself because you had the right answer. I have changed mine to reflect the correction

Comment: @Raj - Thanks.  I do prefer the DateAdd/DateDiff method that your solution uses, although I was amazed at the upvoters who clearly didn't run your original SQL or check the result!

Answer (score 11):

**EDIT:** This was returning current year, when the question was for previous year. Code has been corrected to reflect this.

use this

```
select DATEADD(yy, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0), -1)
```

OR to use your variable:

```
select DATEADD(yy, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,@YourDateTimeValue), 0), -1)
```

Comment: this is a fairly standard thing in SQL Server that everyone should learn, here is a link that shows how to do it for year, month, day, hour, minute... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85373/floor-a-date-in-sql-server

Comment: This answer produces the WRONG result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, 365, GETDATE()), 0)
```

Comment: SELECT DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, 365, GETDATE()), 0) Not work with leap year:(