# Get row where datetime column = today

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

In sql 2005, instead of building a query from dateparts year, month and date,

is there an more succinct way of writing the where clause?

Comment: I'm wondering whether any of the answers are anymore succinct than this. I find this more readable too.
where (DATEPART(yy, myColum) = '2010') 
AND (DATEPART(mm, myColum) = '4') 
AND (DATEPART(dd, myColum) = '7');

Comment: **@Chin, your method will prevent index usage, and will result in a slow table scan.** I would highly recommend that you NEVER search based on a date using that method.  You need to "floor" the dates in the range, and apply no functions to the column if you want to use an index.  this is how to floor a datetime: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85373/floor-a-date-in-sql-server

Comment: @KM, thanks for that. I thought I'd ask and see whether I was off base.  Currently I'm unaware of an index on this column. I'll keep this in mind though and floor my dates as you have suggested.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the date part only from a SQL Server datetime datatype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In SQL 2000 and SQL 2005 you can use a nice select statement to remove the time component from a DateTime, ie

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()), 0)
```

will return 6-Apr-2010 (well for today only).

So combined with marc_s's answer, you'd want

```
SELECT (list of fields)
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE dateValue BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,'MY Date and Time, But I Only Want Date'), 0) 
AND DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,'MY Date and Time, But I Only Want Date'), 1)
```

Edit: Changed to suit requirements, note the 1 in the second DateAdd (this adds the days it has been from the beginning to 1 (instead of 0), making it 7th Apr 2010 00:00:00)
If you want 6th Apr 23:59:59 you take a second away from the second date

```
DATEADD(ss,-1,'My DateTime')
```

Final Call would become

```
DATEADD(ss,-1,DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,'MY Date and Time, But I Only Want Date'), 1))
```

Ok that's alot of info at once! Hope it all makes sense :)

Comment: I like your expression to get the date-only part better than my solution - but this select won't work, no?? If you have '2010-04-06 15:15:15' - how is comparing that to just the date part going to select that?? I think you need a `WHERE dateValue BETWEEN (today) AND (today+1 day)` kind of select to grab all those values today with any time-portion attached to them....

Comment: If you want to completely destroy the indexes, you could use the DateAdd/DatePart on the DateValue, but that's a bad idea! (If you have good indexes :) )

Comment: I have had times that are between 23:59:59.000 and 00:00:00.000 the next day eliminated from reports. so I would never use the "subtract one second method".  It is better to keep the time at 00:00:000.000 and increment one day and just use "<" less than (yourColumn < FlooredEndRangeDateTime+1)

Answer (score 35):

On SQL Server 2008, you would have a new `DATE` data type, which you could use to achieve this:

```
SELECT (list of fields)
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE dateValue BETWEEN 
   CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

The `CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)` casts the current date and time to a date-only value, e.g. return '2010-04-06' for April 6, 2010. Adding one day to that basically selects all datetime values of today.

In SQL Server 2005, there's no easy way to do this - the most elegant solution [I found here](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/functions/get-date-only.aspx) is using numeric manipulation of the DATETIME to achieve the same result:

```
SELECT (list of fields)
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE dateValue BETWEEN 
   CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) AND 
   DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME))
```

Comment: @marc_s - did you just delete your answer? freaked me out as I was trying to add a comment. If only I cud upgrade. Thanks for your help though much appreciated.

Comment: @Chin: yes, I had a silly answer first, deleted it, edited it, and undeleted it again :-)

Comment: @marc_s: You sure have a deranged definition of the word "elegant", +1 :)

Comment: OK - I think PostMan's way to extracting only the date-part of a DATETIME is probably even more elegant ;-)

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for this, How do you think this would perform in comparison with using 3 datepart clauses?

Comment: @Chin: if you have an index on the datetime field, it should be fairly OK in terms of performance. If you add the three parts Year,Month,Day to your table as computed fields and put an index on those three fields, it would be even better since it only needs to do an equality match (Year=2010,Month=04,Day=06) rather than a range query.

Comment: Gotcha, this has been very insightful.

Answer (score 5):

Not good performance, but a solution:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblDate
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, date, 112) = CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112);
```

If it is a common query a computed column should be added with only year-month-day content.

Comment: you are correct, it will be slow, because no index will be used

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of this

```
CONVERT(date,tbldata.date)=CONVERT(date,getdate())
```

This assumes that the date column includes the time as well. If it does not then you can change it to

```
tbldata.date=CONVERT(date,getdate())
```

Comment: Sql Server 2005 has a `date` type? ;)

Comment: Turns out it does not. My current stack is SQL server 2008 its been a while since we upgraded and I assumed that 2005 had this feature.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a UDF to do this on datetime columns going back to SQL 2000.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GETDATENOTIME](@now datetime)
RETURNS smalldatetime
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (CONVERT(smalldatetime, CONVERT(varchar, @now, 112)))
END
```

Usage:

```
DECLARE @date smalldatetime
SET @date = '4/1/10'
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE dbo.GETDATENOTIME(date) = @date
```

Not the most efficient thing in the world (YMMV depending on your table) but it does the job.  For tables where I know I'll be selecting based on date-without-time a lot, I'll have a column specifically for that with a default set to dbo.GETDATENOTIME(GETDATE()).

Comment: if you ever had an index on the "date" column, this will definitely not be able to use it and thus result in a table scan....

Comment: Hence my disclaimer at the end.  The OP asked for succinct syntax, so that's the answer I gave him.