# SQL display | select data from today date | current day only

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have this query, it supposes to display data from current date (today) only

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE visitTime <= GETDATE() AND visitTime > GETDATE() - 1
```

where *visitTime* is **datetime** type

But it doesn't work well because I think problem is at `AND visitTime > GETDATE() - 1` but I don't know how to fix this, anybody has any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get row where datetime column = today - SQL server noob](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583228/get-row-where-datetime-column-today-sql-server-noob)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at this example:

```
declare @visitTime datetime  ='2014-10-16 23:59:59.000'
select GETDATE() GETDATE, @visitTime visitTime, GETDATE() - 1 [GETDATE-1]

GETDATE                 visitTime               GETDATE-1
2014-10-17 00:02:18.980 2014-10-16 23:59:59.000 2014-10-16 00:02:18.980
```

You'll see that the visittime date clearly falls in the range you specified as the lower bound (the -1) subtracts a whole day and not just the time part.

You could use this instead:

```
-- using GETDATE() for the upper bound misses visitTime that are 
-- on the current day, but at a later time than now.
WHERE visitTime < DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, GetDate())+1, 0)
AND   visitTime >= DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, GetDate()), 0)
```

or if you're on SQL Server 2008+ that has a`date`data type, this:

```
WHERE CAST(visitTime AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Note that`GETDATE()`is T-SQL specific, the ANSI equivalent is`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: I like it a lot when you not only post the answer but also explain it with examples. Great!

Comment: nice one `CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming today is midnight last night to midnight tonight, you can use following condition

```
Select * from Customer where 
visitTime >=  DateAdd(d, Datediff(d,1, current_timestamp), 1)
and
visitTime < DateAdd(d, Datediff(d,0, current_timestamp), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE visitTime > =  convert(date,getdate()) 
and visitTime <  dateadd(d,1,convert(date,getdate()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
select *
from Customers
where convert(date,createddate) = convert(date,getdate());
```

Answer (score 0):

Gets detail of to date only:
`SELECT * FROM PRODUCTION WHERE CAST(CREATIONDATE AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)`