# Get specific time from getdate()

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm facing an issue when trying to add a condition in my sql request
I want add  a condition i.e date between `DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)` and `current date until 23:59:59`.
How can I specify the second part of condition? 
thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get row where datetime column = today - SQL server noob](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583228/get-row-where-datetime-column-today-sql-server-noob)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do with predicate:

```
someDate < dateadd(dd, 1, cast(getdate() as date))
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually go with the following:

```
somedate >= cast(floor(cast getdate() as float) as datetime) and somedate < cast(ceiling(cast getdate() as float) as datetime)
```

Comment: Seems more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: I find his is a safer way, and is backwards compatible - the "date" type didn't use to exist!