# SQL How to remove duplicates within select query?

Tags: sql

I have a table which looks like that:

[image]

As You see, there are some date duplicates, so how to select only one row for each date in that table?

the column 'id_from_other_table' is from INNER JOIN with the table above

Comment: What database, and what version?

Comment: Hello Tony, I found this to be useful when I was trying to do a similar thing. It does not answer your question and remove the duplicates but it helps give a count which might be relevant:
COUNT(*) - COUNT(DISTINCT name) AS 'duplicate name'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mention that there are date duplicates, but it appears they're quite unique down to the precision of seconds.

Can you clarify what precision of date you start considering dates duplicate - day, hour, minute?

In any case, you'll probably want to [floor your datetime field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85373/floor-a-date-in-sql-server/85379#85379). You didn't indicate *which field is preferred* when removing duplicates, so this query will prefer the last name in alphabetical order.

```
 SELECT MAX(owner_name), 
        --floored to the second
        dateadd(second,datediff(second,'2000-01-01',start_date),'2000-01-01') AS StartDate
 From   MyTable
 GROUP BY dateadd(second,datediff(second,'2000-01-01',start_date),'2000-01-01')
```

Comment: I consider year, month, date, and hh:mm:ss

Answer (score 23):

There are multiple rows with the same date, but the time is different. Therefore, DISTINCT start_date will not work. What you need is: cast the start_date to a DATE (so the TIME part is gone), and then do a DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(start_date AS DATE) FROM table;
```

Depending on what database you use, the type name for DATE is different.

Answer (score 12):

Do you need any other information except the date? If not:

```
SELECT DISTINCT start_date FROM table;
```

Comment: The dates are the same, but the times are different; as such, `DISTINCT` won't work on `start_date` without some formatting

Answer (score 3):

```
Select Distinct CAST(FLOOR( CAST(start_date AS FLOAT ) )AS DATETIME) from Table
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to select any random single row for particular day, then

```
SELECT * FROM table_name GROUP BY DAY(start_date)
```

If you want to select single entry for each user per day, then

```
SELECT * FROM table_name GROUP BY DAY(start_date),owner_name
```

Answer (score 2):

here is the solution for your query returning only one row for each date in that table
here in the solution 'tony' will occur twice as two different start dates are there for it

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT T1.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TRUNC(START_DATE),OWNER_NAME ORDER BY 1,2 DESC )  RNM
    FROM TABLE T1
)
WHERE RNM=1
```

Comment: hi @zessx how you edited it ,i put the formatted code as you edited but after posting,it did't appear as it is now  ,how u do it ???

Comment: Pasting formatted code is not enough (in fact, it does nothing). You need to paste your code, select it and use `Ctrl+K` (or click on the `{}` button in the StackOverflow editor). You also can do it manually, adding 4 spaces before each line of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the "DateTime" to a "Date".  Then you can easier select just one for the given date no matter the time for that date.