# SQL: Get list of names form database without double occurences

Tags: sql, list, sorting

I am doing my first experiences with sql. I am currently working on a genealogical website feeded by an sql database. By the time the number of persons in the db has increased an I want to implement a short way to navigate to a specific person by a few clicks.
Therefore, I want to first give a list of all family names within the database.
The sql for this is quite simple:

`SELECT familyname FROM tablewithdata ORDER BY familyname;`

This obviously gives me a list like this:

- Griffin
- Griffin
- Griffin
- Miller
- Miller
- Miller
- Sanchez
- Sanchez
- Simpson
- Simpson
- Simpson
- Simpson
  ...

The occurrences of the family names are as much as the individuals with this name in the db.

But I want to have only one occurrence of each family name in the database like this:

- Griffin
- Miller
- Sanchez
- Simpson

I hope there is a simple solution for my request. My Google search only resulted in ways I can remove the double entries from my database.

Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL How to remove duplicates within select query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695369/sql-how-to-remove-duplicates-within-select-query)

Comment: Do you want to just _view_ your data this way, or do you actually want to remove "duplicates," however you have defined them?

Answer (score 1):

Use `select distinct familyname FROM tablewithdata ORDER BY familyname;`

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL [DISTINCT](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-distinct-keyword.htm) keyword is used in conjunction with the SELECT statement to eliminate all the duplicate records and fetching only unique records.

```
SELECT DISTINCT familyname 
FROM tablewithdata 
ORDER BY familyname;
```

To remove duplicate entries from database, you can use ROW_Number() concept here.

```
DELETE FROM
(
  SELECT familyname, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTTION BY familyname ORDER BY familyname) 
  RN
  FROM tablewithdata;
) X WHERE RN > 1
```

Comment: Your delete query looks to be Oracle, and in any case would be database specific.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Group By:

```
SELECT familyname FROM tablewithdata GROUP BY familyname ORDER BY familyname
```

Comment: Great! This Worked!!

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT distinct(familyname) FROM tablewithdata ORDER BY familyname

. This should help you.