# Convert from DateTime to INT

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

In my SSIS package, I have to converting values from DateTime to a corresponding INTEGER value. The following sample has been provided.

Any ideas as to how I can convert these?

```
DATETIME   INT
---------  ----
1/1/2009   39814
2/1/2009   39845
3/1/2009   39873
4/1/2009   39904
5/1/2009   39934
6/1/2009   39965
7/1/2009   39995
8/1/2009   40026
9/1/2009   40057
10/1/2009  40087
11/1/2009  40118
12/1/2009  40148
1/1/2010   40179
2/1/2010   40210
3/1/2010   40238
4/1/2010   40269
5/1/2010   40299
6/1/2010   40330
```

Comment: `SELECT CAST(CAST('20090101' AS DATETIME) AS INT) + 2?`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

EDIT: Casting to a float/int no longer works in recent versions of SQL Server. Use the following instead:

```
select datediff(day, '1899-12-30T00:00:00', my_date_field)
from mytable
```

Note the string date should be in an [unambiguous date format](http://www.karaszi.com/SQLServer/info_datetime.asp) so that it isn't affected by your server's regional settings.

---

In older versions of SQL Server, you can convert from a DateTime to an Integer by casting to a float, then to an int:

```
select cast(cast(my_date_field as float) as int)
from mytable
```

(NB: You can't cast straight to an int, as MSSQL rounds the value up if you're past mid day!)

If there's an offset in your data, you can obviously add or subtract this from the result

You can convert in the other direction, by casting straight back:

```
select cast(my_integer_date as datetime)
from mytable
```

Comment: The OP doesn't have any time component (shown at least). `datetime` is stored as 2 ints so you could also cast as binary, and cast the first 4 bytes to int. `SELECT CAST(substring(CAST(CAST('20090101 15:00:00' AS DATETIME) AS BINARY(8)),1,4) AS INT)`

Comment: True - but better safe than sorry!

Comment: It does not work ?! for date format it throws error "Explicit conversion from data type date to float is not allowed." and for datetime it throws
"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using @Muflix?

Answer (score 10):

> select DATEDIFF(dd, '12/30/1899', mydatefield)

Comment: Why do we use 12/30/1899 and not 12/31/1899?

Comment: @SeanBrookins It's been a long while, but iirc it has to do with a date bug in Lotus Notes from way back in the early 80's, where Excel copied the behavior in order to be compatible with Notes, and everything else has since copied Excel.

Comment: The fact that you responded and not somebody different is already astounding, but within 35 minutes no need to apologize at all! I checked and this does create compatibility with Excel, so that makes sense. Weird!

Comment: I get notices for new comments :)

Answer (score 0):

Or, once it's already in SSIS, you could create a derived column (as part of some data flow task) with:

```
(DT_I8)FLOOR((DT_R8)systemDateTime)
```

But you'd have to test to doublecheck.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert to an `int` and if you know the style of the date, like here `104` for `31.12.2024`, then you can convert to the default date format `2024-12-31` with `convert(date, my_date, 104)`, make this a `char(10)`, and then replace `'-'` with `''` so and make that an `int`.

```
select convert(int, replace(convert(char(10),convert(date, '31.12.2024', 104)), '-',''))
```

But this can be made shorter. The conversion to char itself can get a date style as well, see [format date to 105 in SQL Server after casting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6280834/11154841):

```
select convert(char(10),convert(date, '31.12.2024', 104), 112)
```

Output:

`'20241231'`

And this only needs to be converted to `int`:

```sql
select convert(int, convert(char(10),convert(date, '31.12.2024', 104), 112))
```

Output is the integer `20241231`.