# format date to 105 in SQL Server after casting

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, casting

I have a problem: I have a datetime and I need the date to specific format

So I just casted datetime to time

```
SELECT CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE) -- result (2011-06-08)
```

and for formatting I use convert

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE), 105) --result (2011-06-08)

105 format (dd-mm-yy)
```

but, the result of both is same,

`CONVERT` is not working for 105 formatting,

Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the results you're looking for you need to convert the DATE to a VARCHAR like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE),105)
```

If you cast to a DATE, you will always get the full DATE.

You can truncate the date by re-casting to the DATE type.

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE),105) as DATE)
```

Comment: but this way i get the result in varchar, can i get it as Date with my formatting

Comment: I have updated my answer, hopefully that is what you're looking for.

Comment: finally casting it to DATETIME just adds the time to it. but don't format it to 105 code

Comment: Can you just cast to DATE instead of DATETIME? If that's not what you want then I think I must not understand what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as

`SELECT Convert(varchar, getdate(), 105)`

Comment: but this way i get the result in varchar, can i get it as Date with my formatting

Answer (score -1):

```
select convert(varchar(50),date,105) as Date
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.