# how can i convert a datetime to int?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert from DateTime to INT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505935/convert-from-datetime-to-int)

For performance reasons, I would like to add a computed column to my table.

I am doing lots of queries like this:

```
select * from mytable where mydate between @start_date and @end_date
```

instead of the above query I would like to do this:

```
select * from mytable where my_computed_column between number1 and number2
```

What is the best way to convert `datetime` to `int`?

Comment: What are you storing in the int? Posix time?  Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505935/convert-from-datetime-to-int

Comment: What accuracy you need for it? You can use DATEDIFF to the 0-date if there no milliseconds needed in result.

Comment: @climbage great answer! posix time looks great!