# Convert DateTime to Int

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime, int

This is the sample I did in SQL Server

```
SELECT CAST(CAST('2012-01-25 10:00:00.000' AS DATETIME) AS INT) + 2
```

Result is 40933

How can I achieve this using c#? From where and how this integer comes?

Reference: [Convert from DateTime to INT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505935/convert-from-datetime-to-int) but this is what I need in c#

Comment: Why do you want to do it in C#?

Comment: because i am working on app which use service and i can't use sql procedure there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't understand why you would need to represent a `DateTime` as an integer in C#, but you can use this method:

```
public static int DateTimeToInt(DateTime theDate)
{
    return (int)(theDate.Date - new DateTime(1900, 1, 1)).TotalDays + 2;
}
```

And you can use this method for the reverse operation:

```
public static DateTime IntToDateTime(int intDate)
{
    return new DateTime(1900, 1, 1).AddDays(intDate - 2);
}
```

Comment: Thanku so much, i need this because there is field in Database which represent DateTime as this integer, i guess it is for optimization....
and i am working on window store app which is extension of existing app...and only way to communicate is though DB is service so, i need to do all manipulation in my PCL's

Comment: @Arun: [bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) - you should **not** store dates as strings or ints - you're just asking for trouble that way. Use the `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatypes!

Comment: @Klaus could you please mention why this +/- 2 for?

Comment: @marc_s - there is DateTime fields but, there are separate fields for this integer values to optimize query....anyway i can't access db as  i am at another end....thanks for concern :)

Comment: @Rezoan the +/- 2 is taken from the OP's example

Answer (score 2):

extension to cast dateTime to timestamp

```
public static int DateTimeToInt(this DateTime theDate)
{
    int unixTime = (int)(DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;
    return unixTime;
}
```

better to cast dateTime to long, use property `DateTime.Ticks` for this