# Error select from sqlserver - 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a problem with date conversion and the displayed error. I think the block below is the problem.

I need to bring the difference between the dates and calculate them to know if the invoice is open "A" or downloaded "B", but it is returning the error below.

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '30/12/' to datatype int.
```

```
            <pre><code>
            SELECT [vl_recebido]
            ,[vl_pago]
            ,[vl_original]
            ,s.[dt_baixa]
            ,[dt_vencto]
            ,[dt_rp]
            ,S.[id_divisao]
            ,[nro_baixa]
            ,S.[nm_cliente]
            ,ISNULL(C.id_cliente, -1) AS id_cliente
            ,[nro_documento]
            ,[ds_moeda]
            ,[cd_cc]
            ,[cd_t_cta]
            ,[cd_port]
            ,[cd_oper]
            ,[ds_observacao]
            ,[ds_complemento]
            ,[nm_resp_baixa]
            ,[qtd_recibo]
            ,[qtd_pagto]
            ,t.[qtd_colaborador]
            ,t.[vl_meta]
            ,[flag]
            ,[bco_sacado]
            ,[cheque_numero]
            ,[in_processo]
            ,isnull(af.id_aging_fatura, 5) as id_aging_fatura
            ,af.dsc_faixa_aging
            ,af.qtd_aging
            ,datediff(d, s.dt_vencto, s.dt_baixa) as qtd_aging_calc
            ,case when s.dt_baixa is null then 'A' else 'B' end as status_da_fatura
            FROM stg_recibo_baixas S
            LEFT JOIN dim_cliente C ON C.cod_cliente = S.cod_cliente
                AND C.id_divisao = S.id_divisao
            INNER JOIN tab_colaborador_baixa t ON t.id_mes = CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), s.dt_baixa, 112))
            left join dim_aging_faturas af on af.qtd_aging = (select min(qtd_aging) from dim_aging_faturas a
            where a.qtd_aging >= case when datediff(d, s.dt_vencto, case when s.dt_baixa is null then getdate() else convert(datetime, substring(s.dt_baixa, 8, 4) + '-' + substring(s.dt_baixa, 4, 2) +'-'+ substring(s.dt_baixa, 0, 2), 103) end) < 0 then 0 else datediff(d, s.dt_vencto, convert(datetime, substring(s.dt_baixa, 8, 4) + '-' + substring(s.dt_baixa, 4, 2) +'-'+ substring(s.dt_baixa, 0, 2), 103)) end)
            </code></pre>
```

Comment: clearly this `30/12/`  can't be converted to int,check this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505935/convert-from-datetime-to-int

Comment: what is the dataType of this column "dt_baixa" and give us some example data from this column.

Comment: I got it sorted out. Thank you.