# Explicit conversion from data type date to int is not allowed

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012, type-conversion

I am trying to calculate AGE of contracts, however I am getting the error

> Explicit conversion from data type date to int is not allowed

This is my code:

```
SELECT 
    Contract_hist.*,
    IB.*,
    CAST((CASE
             WHEN (CAST(CONVERT(INT, Setup.[Start]) - CONVERT(INT,[IB].[Install_Date])) AS INT))/365 <= 0 
                THEN 0  
             WHEN (CAST(CONVERT(INT, Setup.[Start]) - CONVERT(INT,[IB].[Install_Date])) AS INT)) / 365 > 0 
                THEN (CAST(CONVERT(INT, Setup.[Start]) CONVERT(INT,[IB].[Install_Date])) AS INT)) / 365 
          END) AS INT) AS AGE
FROM 
    Setup, Contract_hist
INNER JOIN 
    IB ON Contract_hist.[System No] = IB.System_ID
```

Where "Setup.[Start]" & "[IB].[Install_Date]" are *datetime2* values.

Comment: Does this relate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505935/convert-from-datetime-to-int "casting to an int no longer works in recent versions of sql server'. try using `DATEDIFF(dd, '12/30/1899', mydatefield)`.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged. And you should **most definitely NOT** mix the two styles !

Comment: So, what do you suggest? What kind of `join` should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
SELECT 
Contract_hist.*
,IB.*
,CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(year,[IB].[Install_Date], Setup.[Start] ) <= 0 THEN 0
        ELSE DATEDIFF(year, [IB].[Install_Date], Setup.[Start])
 END AS AGE

FROM Setup, Contract_hist
    INNER JOIN IB ON Contract_hist.[System No] = IB.System_ID
```

Answer (score 3):

You could convert those datetime2 fields first to datetime, then to an int.

```
(convert(int, convert(datetime, Setup.[Start])) - convert(int,convert(datetime, [IB].[Install_Date])))/365
```

But that can be shortened to:

```
cast(convert(datetime, Setup.[Start]) - convert(datetime, IB.[Install_Date]) as int)/365
```

Or you could simplify it even more and calculate the difference in years directly with [datediff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql):

```
datediff(year, [IB].[Install_Date], Setup.[Start])
```

And that CASE can also be simplified:

```
case 
when datediff(year, [IB].[Install_Date], Setup.[Start]) > 0 
then datediff(year, [IB].[Install_Date], Setup.[Start])
else 0
end as AGE
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like casting to a float/int is not supported in the latter versions of sql server. Try using `DATEDIFF(dd, '12/30/1899', mydatefield)`