# How to count the rows with different dates in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I need to get sum of days. The sum should be a number.
For summing should be taken only unique dates.
In below table there are 3 records for userid 1.
I need to get result equal 2 because he worked 2 days, `04.06.2018` and `05.06.2018`.

```
UserID  Date
1       04.06.2018 10:45:11
1       04.06.2018 17:15:11
1       05.06.2018 09:15:33
```

Desired result is:

```
UserID  TotalDays
1       2
```

How to achive that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get `TotalDays` per user:

```sql
SELECT UserId, COUNT(DISTINCT DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, Date)) TotalDays
FROM UserDate
GROUP BY UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it myself.

```sql
-- Bad query
SELECT count(distinct CAST(Date as int))

-- Slightly better
SELECT count(distinct cast(cast(Date as float) as int))
```

**Note**: It's [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5505975/1657465) to cast straight to an int, as MSSQL rounds the value up if you're past mid day!

Comment: Be careful, `CAST(Date as int)` can return the same value for 2 dates with different days

Comment: could you provide an example?

Comment: Just run this on your table: `SELECT Date, CAST(Date as int) FROM table`. In your example, 2nd and 3rd dates have different days, but the query will return 43254 for both.

Comment: Yes it's true, but I don't care about time but only date. Although, my approach isn't as elegant as yours. I changed my procedure, thank you very much.