# SQL datetime needs to read 00:00:00.000

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following piece of SQL:

```
select DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0))
```

which comes through as this format:

```
2012-02-29 23:59:59.000
```

I need the exact piece of code with the date the same, however the time part must read 00:00:00.000

Modify* I should have been clear here: I need to have the last day of previous month at any given time (with the time in 00:00:00.000 format of course)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Floor a date in SQL server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85373/floor-a-date-in-sql-server)

Comment: `SELECT CAST(s AS DATE)` or `SELECT CAST(CAST(s As Date) As DateTime)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select dateadd(d,datediff(d,0,dateadd(s,-1,dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,getdate()),0))),0)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())))
```

Comment: OP's query gives the last day / second of the previous month. Your query gives the 1st second of today.

Comment: This wont work, as he is subtracting a month from the current month.

Comment: SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())))

Comment: This removes the time part and goes back one month. Try it for date  `2012-03-14T10:00:00` and you will see that it does not give `2012-02-29 00:00:00.000` as output.

Comment: FYI he want's it to go back one month.  The answer is correct

Comment: You have misunderstood the question. He wants `2012-02-29 00:00:00.000` for **all** dates in March.

Comment: @general exception - yes, 1 hour ago when the question was first posted. I updated it to reflect the answer in the comment :)

Comment: @MikaelEriksson - marked as the answer, must have been what he was looking for.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: @general exception marked as the answer, must have been what he was looking for. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @DarrenDavies - I think not. Your query will give the answer he wants today, tomorrow and on Saturday but on Sunday he will be disappointed.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson OP has modified question, looks like he wants to return the last day of the previous month in the said format (without time).

Comment: @generalexception - Yes, that is what I thought all the time. And you as well since your answer does exactly that.

Answer (score 3):

This will give you the last second of the prior month

```
select dateadd(s,-1,dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,GETDATE()),0));
```

and this will give you the last day of the prior month

```
select dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,GETDATE()),0));
```

---

More details of how to do this:

```
select dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,@datetime),0);
```

or

```
select dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0);
```

In English: Take the number of days between this date and 0 and add those days to 0.

This works with any parameter for datediff.  So

```
select dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,GETDATE()),0);
```

Will "remove" all day information in addition to time information.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative method to strip out the time portion is to cast it to a float, apply the `Floor` function and cast back to a datetime.

```
select Cast(Floor(Cast(DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0)) as float)) as datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

In SQL Server 2012 you could use `eomonth`.

```
SELECT EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: I tried your date you suggested in your comment.  It gave the correct output?

Comment: @DarrenDavies - Check this out and notice the differences of the dates between our answers and the query provided in the question. [End-Of-Month](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/65491/end-of-month)

Answer (score 0):

Saw some similar posts

```
select  cast(cast(dateadd(dd,-1,getdate()) as date) as datetime)
```

Cast your dateadd as a date and then enclose it in another cast back to datetime

So it goes from this
   2012-02-29 23:59:59.000

To this
   2012-02-29

and the finally this
   2012-02-29 00:00:00.000