# Between Date is not working in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2012

I have a very simple SQL which select data from a range of date. So, for example if I have,

```
SELECT ...... WHERE PV.[Time] BETWEEN '02/26/2014' AND '02/26/2014'
```

This SQL Select statement is not selecting the data in 02/26/2014. Please help

Comment: You should convert formats with [`CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: Well - are there any rows where time equals 02/26/2014?
And if so, is your SQL Server is set up to handle dates in that format? What if you try to change the query to: '20142602' AND '20142602'

Comment: Don't use `BETWEEN` here anyway. Unless the intention is to include rows which have exactly midnight on 26 Feb but no other times on that date.

Comment: @MartinSmith, then what should I do? Allen, yes there are rows

Comment: and what does this return: `SELECT DISTINCT PV.[Time] From PV WHERE PV.[Time] BETWEEN '02/25/2014' AND '02/27/2014'` - do your time columns have a time component?

Comment: Is PV.[Time] inclusive a times segment? Because if so, and you want to use between you'll need to include the time in the between.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen, I don't want to include time.

Comment: @user960567 in reference to MartinSmith's comment about inclusion of rows for an inclusive date, I've used the CAST CEILING trick with great success, thus excluding the time `CAST(CEILING(CAST(@MyDate AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)`. Floor also works. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85373/floor-a-date-in-sql-server

Comment: cast your PV.[Time] to a date without time segment

Comment: @Tom - That isn't sargable.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen - [That isn't optimal](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea)

Comment: @MartinSmith Would you recommend the DateAdd method instead?

Comment: @Tom - Neither. The time component is in the values in the `PV.[Time]` column. Applying almost any function to a column makes it unsargable (can't use an index). Casting to date is kind of sargable but not as efficient as simply doing the range seek on `>= ... <`

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks for the explanation, I learnt something today!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current statement `BETWEEN '02/26/2014' AND '02/26/2014'` has the same value on the left and right and so is equivalent to `= '02/26/2014'`.

This will only bring back rows at midnight on 26 Feb. Use

```
 WHERE PV.[Time] >= '20140226' AND PV.[Time] < '20140227'
```

Comment: Means this will not take the time. bring all records on 26 date?

Comment: @user960567 - Yes this will bring back all rows for the 26th irrespective of time component.

Comment: Very Nice. Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It's always preferable to use a non-dubious string format for dates (`1/2/2000` can be interpreted as 01-feb-2000 or 02-jan-2000, depending on your local settings). I prefer the ISO format `yyyymmdd` or ODBC canonical `yyyy-mm-dd` and always use `CONVERT` to be explicit when handling dates. But this is not your problem :)

The problem with your query is that you are actually filtering dates `BETWEEN '02/26/2014 00:00:00' AND '02/26/2014 00:00:00'`, thus you'll only get values at exactly the datetime. To get datetime values through whole day `02/26/2014` use the following:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE PV.[Time] >= '2014-02-26' AND PV.[Time] < dateadd(day, 1, '2014-02-26');
```

Comment: You were right, @MartinSmith, I was aware of this edge-case, but did not consider as significant. The code was corrected to be completely correct.