# Retrieving all the rows from a table if a match is found in month and year of a datetime field

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I am working on an SQL Query where I need to retrieve all the rows from the SQL table where a DateTime field as the Month and Year supplied no matter what the day and time is

My SQL QUERY is as follows

```
SELECT * From Table where DateCreated=@selectedDate
```

Table

```
Id Product Quantity Price DateCreated
1  abc     20        10   2014-12-04 12:26:44.457
2  xyz      25       15   2014-12-14 12:26:44.457
```

from the above table it should return all the rows with month 12 and year 2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM aTable
  WHERE MONTH(DateCreated) = MONTH(@selectedDate) AND
        YEAR(DateCreated) = YEAR(@selectedDate)
```

Sometimes the answer is just simple.

If you really want to get fancy you could use the technique mentioned here 
[Floor a date in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85373/floor-a-date-in-sql-server) like so:

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM aTable
  WHERE 
      dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,DateCreated),0) = 
      dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,@selectedDate),0);
```

Comment: Be aware this method will force a table scan regardless of indexes...if it's a large table you'd be better off making a range to compare against.

Comment: @JNK - Is that true -- I know on DB2 the YEAR function will do a seek on an indexed date column... does SQL Server act different?

Comment: I am pretty certain in the SQL Server `MONTH` is non-sargable. `YEAR` MIGHT be but I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

This will use an index on DateCreated

```
SELECT *
FROM aTable
WHERE DateCreated >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@selectedDate),MONTH(@selectedDate),1)
  AND DateCreated <  DATEADD(month,1,DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@selectedDate),MONTH(@selectedDate),1))
```