# SQL select from multiple tables based on datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, datetime2

I am working on a script to analyze some data contained in thousands of tables on a SQL Server 2008 database.

For simplicity sakes, the tables can be broken down into groups of 4-8 semi-related tables. By semi-related I mean that they are data collections for the same item but they do not have any actual SQL relationship. Each table consists of a date-time stamp (`datetime2` data type), value (can be a `bit`, `int`, or `float` depending on the particular item), and some other columns that are currently not of interest. The date-time stamp is set for every 15 minutes (on the quarter hour) within a few seconds; however, not all of the data is recorded precisely at the same time...

For example:

TABLE1:

```
TIMESTAMP                 VALUE
2014-11-27 07:15:00.390      1
2014-11-27 07:30:00.390      0
2014-11-27 07:45:00.373      0
2014-11-27 08:00:00.327      0
```

TABLE2:

```
TIMESTAMP                 VALUE
2014-11-19 08:00:07.880      0
2014-11-19 08:15:06.867      0.0979999974370003
2014-11-19 08:30:08.593      0.0979999974370003
2014-11-19 08:45:07.397      0.0979999974370003
```

TABLE3

```
TIMESTAMP                 VALUE
2014-11-27 07:15:00.390        0
2014-11-27 07:30:00.390        0
2014-11-27 07:45:00.373        1
2014-11-27 08:00:00.327        1
```

As you can see, not all of the tables will start with the same quarterly `TIMESTAMP`. Basically, what I am after is a query that will return the VALUE for each of the 3 tables for every 15 minute interval starting with the earliest `TIMESTAMP` out of the 3 tables. For the example given, I'd want to start at 2014-11-27 07:15  (don't care about seconds... thus, would need to allow for the timestamp to be +- 1 minute or so).  Returning NULL for the value when there is no record for the particular TIMESTAMP is ok.  So, the query for my listed example would return something like:

```
TIMESTAMP                 VALUE1   VALUE2             VALUE3
2014-11-27 07:15           1    NULL                  0
2014-11-27 07:30           0    NULL                  0
2014-11-27 07:45           0    NULL                  1
2014-11-27 08:00           0    NULL                  1
...
2014-11-19 08:00           0         0                        1
2014-11-19 08:15           0         0.0979999974370003       0
2014-11-19 08:30           0         0.0979999974370003       0
2014-11-19 08:45           0         0.0979999974370003       0
```

I hope this makes sense.  Any help/pointers/guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I would do is normalize the timestamps to the minute.  You can do this with an update to the existing column

```
UPDATE TABLENAME
  SET TIMESTAMP = dateadd(minute,datediff(minute,0,TIMESTAMP),0)
```

or in a new column

```
ALTER TABLE TABLENAME ADD COLUMN NORMTIME DATETIME;

UPDATE TABLENAME
  SET NORMTIME = dateadd(minute,datediff(minute,0,TIMESTAMP),0)
```

For details on flooring dates this see this post: [Floor a date in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85373/floor-a-date-in-sql-server)

---

The next step is to make a table that has all of the timestamps (normalized) that you expect to see -- that is every 15 -- one per row.  Lets call this table TIME_PERIOD and the column EVENT_TIME for my examples (call it whatever you want).

There are many ways to make such a table recursive CTE, ROW_NUMBER(), even brute force.  I leave that part up to you.

---

Now the problem is simple select with left joins and a filter for valid values like this:

```
SELECT TP.EVENT_TIME, a.VALUE as VALUE1, b.VALUE as VALUE2, c.VALUE as VALUE3
FROM  TIME_PERIOD TP
LEFT JOIN TABLE1 a ON a.[TIMESTAMP] = TP.EVENT_TIME
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 b ON b.[TIMESTAMP] = TP.EVENT_TIME
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 c ON c.[TIMESTAMP] = TP.EVENT_TIME
WHERE COALESCE(a.[TIMESTAMP], b.[TIMESTAMP], c.[TIMESTAMP]) is not null
ORDER  BY TP.EVENT_TIME DESC
```

The where might get a little more complex if they are different types so you can always use this (which is not as good as coalesce but will always work):

```
WHERE a.[TIMESTAMP] IS NOT NULL OR
      b.[TIMESTAMP] IS NOT NULL OR
      c.[TIMESTAMP] IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Full Outer Join`

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.[TIMESTAMP], b.[TIMESTAMP], c.[TIMESTAMP]) [TIMESTAMP],
       Isnull(Max(a.VALUE), 0)                               VALUE1,
       Max(b.VALUE)                                          VALUE2,
       Isnull(Max(c.VALUE), 0)                               VALUE3
FROM   TABLE1 a
       FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE2 b
                    ON CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, a.[TIMESTAMP]) = CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, b.[TIMESTAMP])
       FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE3 c
                    ON CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, a.[TIMESTAMP]) = CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, c.[TIMESTAMP])
GROUP  BY COALESCE(a.[TIMESTAMP], b.[TIMESTAMP], c.[TIMESTAMP])
ORDER  BY [TIMESTAMP] DESC
```

Comment: The timestamps have different values -- they won't join with a simple =

Comment: @Hogan - Yep you are right initially i didn't get what you are saying. Updated the answer

Comment: Yes fixed, I like my answer better (I think it will be faster), but this will work.

Comment: Thank you!  I was toying around with the full outer join but kept stumbling into issues with matching up the dates.  Thank you for your assistance

Comment: @mkolker - If any one of the answer served your need then please mark it as answer which will help the other users with similar problem in future

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated version of NoDisplayName's answer that does what you want.  It works for SQL 2012, but you could replace the DATETIMEFROMPARTS function with a series of other functions to get the same result.

```
;WITH 
NewT1 as (
SELECT DATETimeFROMPARTS( DATEPART(year,Timestamp) , DATEPART(month,timestamp) , datepart(day,timestamp),datepart(hour,timestamp), datepart(minute,timestamp),0,0 ) as TimeStamp, Value
FROM Table1),
NewT2 as (
SELECT DATETimeFROMPARTS( DATEPART(year,Timestamp) , DATEPART(month,timestamp) , datepart(day,timestamp),datepart(hour,timestamp), datepart(minute,timestamp),0,0 ) as TimeStamp, Value
FROM Table2),
NewT3 as (
SELECT DATETimeFROMPARTS( DATEPART(year,Timestamp) , DATEPART(month,timestamp) , datepart(day,timestamp),datepart(hour,timestamp), datepart(minute,timestamp),0,0 ) as TimeStamp, Value
FROM Table3)
SELECT COALESCE(a.[TIMESTAMP], b.[TIMESTAMP], c.[TIMESTAMP]) [TIMESTAMPs],
       Isnull(Max(a.VALUE), 0)                            VALUE1,
       Isnull(Max(b.VALUE), 0)                                       VALUE2,
       Isnull(Max(c.VALUE), 0)                                       VALUE3
FROM   NewT1 a
       FULL OUTER JOIN NewT2 b
                    ON a.[TIMESTAMP] = b.[TIMESTAMP]
       FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE3 c
                    ON a.[TIMESTAMP] = b.[TIMESTAMP]
GROUP  BY COALESCE(a.[TIMESTAMP], b.[TIMESTAMP], c.[TIMESTAMP])
ORDER  BY [TIMESTAMPs]
```