# Cast vs Convert SQL Server

Tags: sql, datetime, casting, sql-server-2012, type-conversion

I am constantly working with datetime columns in SQL Server. Now most of the time I have to reset the time portion of the datetime to '00:00:00.000'.

I use the cast function to achieve the same:

```
select cast(cast(getdate() as date)as datetime)
```

Now some other of my team members use other functions:

```
select cast(floor(cast(GETDATE() as float))as datetime)
```

OR

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),105)
```

Which function should I go for keeping in mind that the index column is a datetime type column. (Hence I convert the datetime -> date -> datetime using cast twice).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Floor a date in SQL server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85373/floor-a-date-in-sql-server)

Comment: TLDR; `select dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,@datetime),0);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are good reasons why you should not do the second and third options.  First consider this:

```
select cast(floor(cast(GETDATE() as float)) as datetime)
```

My problem with this is that, although it does work, I cannot find documentation that specifies the behavior.  The internal format is not a floating point number; it is two integers, so I find it quite inelegant to go from a date/time to a float.  There might exist situations where it is dangerous.

Next:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),105)
```

This version . . . Arggh!  It has `varchar()` with no length argument.  Bad habit.  Don't do that! It is a confusing problem waiting to happen.  So, let's consider:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 105)
```

This is fine if you want a string, but the result is different from your other queries.  The equivalent statement is:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 105), 105)
```

But wait, why go through the intermediate structure of a string?  The version you first propose is simpler.

The only downside is that it is not compatible with pre-2008 versions of SQL Server.  If you need to be compatible with earlier versions, then I would go for the yucky:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

This counts the number of days since a fictitious "0" date and then adds them back.  If you don't mind typing, the following is pretty much the same thing:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, '1900-01-01', GETDATE()), '1900-01-01')
```

or go through an intermediate string value.

The reason SQL Server has several work-arounds for this functionality is because the functionality is very useful, but the `date` date type was only introduced in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Thanks Gordon...
For taking time and giving a detailed explanation... :)

Really appreciate it !!!